# JMS Message was not receving using spring JMSTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, jms

I m struggling with simple task with last two days.I have configured jms Message queue in Jboss6.x. I have configured jndi,jms MQ in spring using jmstemplate in applicationcontext.xml File,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd                        
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.test.QueuereceiverDB" /> 

    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">localhost:1099</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jnp.interfaces:org.jboss.naming</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="queueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>ConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="cache">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="QueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="queueConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="destinationResolver">
            <ref bean="jmsDestinationResolver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsSender" class="com.test.MessageSender">
        <property name="jmsTemplate"> <ref bean="QueueTemplate" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="Queue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate"> <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>queue/MyQueue</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmscontainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="queueConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="Queue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
    </bean>
```

Below is Message sender

```
package com.test;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
public class MessageSender {
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void sendMesage() {
        MessageCreator messageCreator=new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws
        JMSException {
        return session.createTextMessage("I am sending Invoice message");}
        };

        jmsTemplate.send("queue/MyQueue", messageCreator);
    }
}
```

Finally Message receiver class

```
public class QueuereceiverDB implements MessageListener {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public QueuereceiverDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see MessageListener#onMessage(Message)
     */

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                System.out.println("Queue: I received a TextMessage at "
                        + new Date());
                TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
                System.out.println("Message is : " + msg.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not valid message for this Queue MDB");
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I have loaded applicationcontext.xml file in web.xml file.
After that deploy the war file in jboss there was no error and also message not received.I dont know why the message was not received.Can someone help me.

After adding resourc-ref tag it shows following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Neither any mapped-name/lookup/jndi-name specified nor any ResourceProvider could process resource-ref named env/ConnectionFactory of type javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
    at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.resource.provider.ResourceRefResourceProviderDelegator.provide(ResourceRefResourceProviderDelegator.java:125) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
    at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.resource.provider.ResourceRefResourceProviderDelegator.provide(ResourceRefResourceProviderDelegator.java:44) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
    at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.JndiEnvironmentProcessor.process(JndiEnvironmentProcessor.java:68) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
    at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.deployer.AbstractSwitchBoardDeployer.process(AbstractSwitchBoardDeployer.java:119) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
    at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.deployer.WebEnvironmentSwitchBoardDeployer.internalDeploy(WebEnvironmentSwitchBoardDeployer.java:66) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
```

The following contains queue name details and deployed in **jboss/server/default/deploy**
mdb-hornetq.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:hornetq"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd" >

    <queue name="MyQueue2" >
        <entry name="/queue/MyQueue" />
    </queue>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you provide code or configuration of receiver to which you actually attach the MessageListener you have defined?

Comment: Thanks aniket.I didnot get you what did you asking exactly?. I have defined MessageListener in  applicationContext.xml file like <bean id="messageListener" class="com.test.QueuereceiverDB" />.I have pasted all source codes.. Can you please explain more?

Comment: It is just a message listener(to receive messages asynchronous).You need to have a QueueReceiver object which calls setMessageListener() function to register a MessageListener which is QueuereceiverDB is your case. I am not very well acquainted with spring but you need a receiver/consumer object/bean to actually receive the messages.

Comment: Ok that part is done by **DefaultMessageListenerContainer(DMLC)**. That bean works as a receiver. I missed that. You code looks as per configurations I googled. Are you actually sending any messages to be received?

Comment: yes aniket.The sender sending simple text message(I am sending Invoice message) to the receiver.I have also configured queue name(queue/MyQueue) in xml file (mdb.hornetq.xml) and placed this file in jboss/server/default/deploy folder.Anything else i missed?

Comment: Your code looks perfectly valid. I am guessing problem is in HoenetQ configuration. It is better that you try running example provided in `hornetq-2.4.0.Beta1/examples/jms/spring-integration`. Check the logs at the same time. Whether you queue us getting registered with the server. There should not be any exceptions in logs/console while deployment.

Comment: You will have to define tour Queue as a ressource in the web.xml . can you share your web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

All is correct , can you verify that in your web.xml you have the ressources declared :

```
<resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>ConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
<resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>queue/MyQueue</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.jms.Queue</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: Thanks Nabil.I have added these lines and run the jboss.It shows some errors. I have added those errors in the questions.please check above. I have also added the configured the file which contains queue details and deployed in jboss/server/default/deploy folder

Comment: try to put in the JNDI name of the JMS connectionFactory a different name . Example : jms/ConnectionFactory and change the line in your web.xml to <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>

Comment: Sorry Nabil.If i change  <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectionFactory</res-ref-name> again same error only shown.Any idea? please help me.

Comment: did you change also the JNDI name :         <property name="jndiName">
            <value>ConnectionFactory</value>
        </property> must be <property name="jndiName">
            <value>jms/ConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>

Comment: yes.I have changed both places applicationContxt.xml and web.xml.but no luck.any idea?